# How to scrape next page from webtable with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape the table with marketvalues per competition from this webpage:

https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa/wettbewerbe?plus=1

I do succeed with the code below:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

tm <- read_html("https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa/wettbewerbe?plus=1")

tbls <- html_nodes(tm, "table")

mydf <- html_table(tbls[1])
mydf <- as.data.frame(mydf)
```

Although I have two problems.

1. The country-names do not show up in `mydf`. (If I copy the table manually from the website and paste it into Excel, the flags are transformed into the country-names.)
2. I do not succeed to import pages 2 till 17 since the table consist of 17 pages. (The 1 at the end of the URL is not related to page 1).

Thanks a lot if someone has any idea how to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check those pagination links, you'll find the argument responsible for the page number. Another option is to disable JavaScript for the site, which you might want to do anyway to get a better idea of how `rvest` "sees" that content. You'll then have real URL in the address bar.

`html_table()` struggles with nested tables and attribute values (competitions & countries). To address those issues, we could drop `html_table()` and instead iterate over `<tr>` elements to build every tibble / data.frame row manually.

Or we could first manipulate the XML tree so that relevant `<td>` elements would only include required data, i.e. replace inline tables and links/images with simple text that `html_table()` can handle:

```r
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# replace nested <td> nodes with <td>image title</td> in XML tree
# xpath_img - xpath to image with title attribute
# xpath_td  - xpath to <td> nodes that will be replaced by <td>image title</td>
image_title_to_td <- function(table_elem, xpath_img, xpath_td){
  td_nodes <- 
    table_elem %>% 
    html_elements(xpath = xpath_img) %>% 
    html_attr("title") %>% 
    { str_glue("<td>{.}</td>") } %>% 
    map(read_xml)
  
  table_elem %>% 
    html_elements(xpath = xpath_td) %>% 
    xml_replace(td_nodes)
  
  table_elem
}

parse_table <- function(html){
  html %>% 
    html_element( "table.items") %>% 
    # handle competitions -- pull image title from inline table
    image_title_to_td("//td/table/tr/td/a/img", "//td[table]") %>% 
    # handle countries -- pull image title from 2nd <td>
    image_title_to_td("./tbody/tr/td[2]/img", "./tbody/tr/td[2]") %>% 
    html_table()
}


url_ <- "https://www.transfermarkt.com/wettbewerbe/europa/wettbewerbe?plus=1"
first_page <- read_html(url_)

# extract last page number (a number after "page=" in url)
last_page_n <- 
  first_page |>
  html_element("li.tm-pagination__list-item--icon-last-page a") |>
  html_attr("href") |>
  str_extract("(?<=page\\=)\\d+") |>
  as.numeric()

# generate URLs for pages 2 ... last_page,
# read all pages,
# insert previously fetched first page into the list,
# extract table from each fetched page,
# cobine list of tables into a single tibble,
# deal with group rows (First Tier, ..., National Youth Super Cup)
paste0(url_, "&page=", 2:last_page_n) %>% 
  map(read_html, .progress = TRUE) %>% 
  append(list(first_page), after = 0) %>% 
  map(parse_table) %>% 
  list_rbind() %>% 
  mutate(grp = Forum, grp = na_if(grp,""), .before = 1, .keep = "unused") %>% 
  fill(grp) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Clubs, "^\\d+$"))
```

Resulting dataset:

```r
#> # A tibble: 425 × 11
#>    grp        Competition        Country     Clubs Player `Avg. age` Foreigners
#>    <chr>      <chr>              <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 First Tier Premier League     England     20    549    26.3       68.9 %    
#>  2 First Tier LaLiga             Spain       20    487    27.4       41.1 %    
#>  3 First Tier Serie A            Italy       20    565    26.1       63.4 %    
#>  4 First Tier Bundesliga         Germany     18    514    25.7       48.2 %    
#>  5 First Tier Ligue 1            France      18    479    25.2       57.0 %    
#>  6 First Tier Liga Portugal      Portugal    18    511    25.5       58.3 %    
#>  7 First Tier Süper Lig          Turkey      20    605    26.5       49.4 %    
#>  8 First Tier Eredivisie         Netherlands 18    471    24.4       47.6 %    
#>  9 First Tier Jupiler Pro League Belgium     16    447    24.6       57.9 %    
#> 10 First Tier Premier Liga       Russia      16    422    26.1       35.8 %    
#> # ℹ 415 more rows
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: `Game ratio of foreign players` <chr>,
#> #   `Goals per match` <chr>, `Average market value` <chr>, `Total value` <chr>
```

---

And just to illustrate XML manipulation, here's the first row of the table in original HTML:

```r
first_page <- read_html(url_)
first_page %>% 
  html_elements("table.items tbody tr") %>% 
  pluck(2) %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  cat()
#> <tr class="odd">
#> <td class="hauptlink"><table class="inline-table"><tr>
#> <td>
#>             <a href="/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1">
#>                 <img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/logo/tiny/gb1.png?lm=1521104656" title="Premier League" alt="Premier League" class="continental-league-emblem"></a>
#>         </td>
#>         <td>
#>             <a href="/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1" title="Premier League">Premier League</a>
#>         </td>
#>     </tr></table></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/flagge/tiny/189.png?lm=1520611569" title="England" alt="England" class="flaggenrahmen"></td>
#> <td class="zentriert">20</td>
#> <td class="zentriert">549</td>
#> <td class="zentriert">26.4</td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><a href="/premier-league/gastarbeiter/wettbewerb/GB1">68.9 %</a></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><a href="/premier-league/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/GB1">71.9 %</a></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><a href="/premier-league/gesamtspielplan/wettbewerb/GB1">3.08</a></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"></td>
#> <td class="rechts">€520.33m</td>
#> <td class="rechts hauptlink">€10.41bn</td>
#> </tr>
```

And after manipulating XML tree, note the change in 2 first `<td>` elements:

```r
first_page %>% 
  html_element("table.items") %>% 
  # change 1st <td> of every row, replace inline table
  image_title_to_td("//td/table/tr/td/a/img", "//td[table]") %>% 
  # change 2st <td> of every row, replace image
  image_title_to_td("./tbody/tr/td[2]/img", "./tbody/tr/td[2]") %>% 
  html_elements("tbody tr") %>% 
  pluck(2) %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  cat()
#> <tr class="odd">
#> <td>Premier League</td>
#> <td>England</td>
#> <td class="zentriert">20</td>
#> <td class="zentriert">549</td>
#> <td class="zentriert">26.4</td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><a href="/premier-league/gastarbeiter/wettbewerb/GB1">68.9 %</a></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><a href="/premier-league/legionaereeinsaetze/wettbewerb/GB1">71.9 %</a></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"><a href="/premier-league/gesamtspielplan/wettbewerb/GB1">3.08</a></td>
#> <td class="zentriert"></td>
#> <td class="rechts">€520.33m</td>
#> <td class="rechts hauptlink">€10.41bn</td>
#> </tr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant code which generates a beautiful solution and gives a clear explanation with several plans of approach. I conclude that scraping is really a subject on its own and quite deep. This is a complete solution for my problem and a very good reference for me (and others too I suppose) to experiment with. Many thanks!